# Java - Javascript regex code fails on 1.8 as compared to 1.7 using javax.script.ScriptEngine;

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I have a regex pattern in JavaScript which works fine in browser and in 1.7  environment of Java using **javax.script.ScriptEngine;** but it fails on 1.8.

My code :

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

String js = "var fileSrc = '<SPAN>06-24-2015  11:28AM  0250 01 90775 05342</SPAN>';"
        + "var trans_regex = /\\<span\\>(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4})\\s*?(\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}\\s*?(?:am|pm))\\s*?(?:<\\/SPAN><BR\\/?><SPAN>)?\\s*?((\\d[ -]*?){13,17})\\s*?\\<\\/span\\>/i ;"
        + "print('executed regex result : ' + trans_regex.exec(fileSrc) ) ; "
        + "var t_time = trans_regex.exec(fileSrc)[2];"
        + "var t_cc = trans_regex.exec(fileSrc)[3];"
        + "print(\" time \" + t_time)";

Object result = engine.eval(js);
```

The result in Java  1.7 environment is :

> executed regex result : 06-24-2015  11:28AM  0250 01 90775
>   05342,06-24-2015,11:28AM,0250 01 90775 05342,2 time 11:28AM

The result in 1.8 environment :

> executed regex result : null Exception in thread "main"
>   javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot get property "2" of
>   null in  at line number 1

the error is comming at this line of my javascript code :  -

> "var t_time = trans_regex.exec(fileSrc)[2];"

Edit :

Following suggestion I created regex group by group and the related question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43341244/regex-for-multiple-group-not-working-java-javax-script-scriptengine-1-8)

Comment: How about putting some `\n`s in the `js` string, so that the line number in your error message is more useful?

Comment: @slim i editted the question with the line causing error in 1.8 java

Comment: @Aaron can you please share the regex string which you used

Comment: @Softxide nevermind, both actually work. Still, there's no reason to escape the `<>`

Comment: @Aaron but I am still getting error on a 1.8 Java environment

Comment: In case you want to share to help other users : https://regex101.com/r/65rB8x/1 (with carets)

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't know why and can't test it with a 1.8 ScriptEngine right now, sorry. I'd suggest simplifying the regex up until it starts working. Then you'll know which feature doesn't behave the same anymore in 1.8

Comment: You might have constraints you have not mentioned, but if you can, you should probably do this directly, without the intermediate JavaScript.

Comment: @mkm13 -  there are no constraints ,I am doing a POC for a bug we facing on a product .

Comment: @Softxide I meant constraints in the production code. There must be a reason you're not simply doing this with java.util.Regex. I hope...

Comment: @mkm13 basically the product using a JS file and render it internally using ScriptEngine  .  My JS file had these line of codes which are not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual problem is shown by the output of the `print`:

```
executed regex result : null
```

So, the regex engine doesn't think your pattern matches the input.

Unsurprisingly `null[2]` doesn't work.

Two points about this:

- You're calling `trans_regex.exec(fileSrc)` three times. Do it once and put the result in a variable.
- Unless you can guarantee a match, you should check for a null result and handle it somehow.

I'd suggest adding a `println` to your Java to print the script and see exactly how the quoting has worked out. Then build up your regex anew from first principles, testing each iteration.

e.g. I truncated the regex down to nothing then rebuilt it as far as:

```
+ "var trans_regex = /<span>(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4})\\s*?(\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}\\s*?(?:am|pm))\\s*?/i;\n"
```

... and it doesn't error any more. Keep adding groups until it fails again. Either the reason will be clear, or you'll have a more focussed question for SO.

It's a bit of a monster regex, so it's not really reasonable to expect SO to debug it for you.

Comment: as you can see my regex in working in 1.7 ,I am looking for any pointers in version difference between 1.7 and 1.8 for ScriptEngine

Comment: If you build up the regex from first principles, as I've suggested, you will identify the part that doesn't work. Then, if you still need to,  you can ask a question containing a short regex.

Comment: I am getting a null on first call of trans_regex.exec(fileSrc) in 1.8 . And again as you can see it works in 1.7

Comment: @Softxide what he means is "I don't know why this doesn't work anymore, here's how to find it". I believe this should be a comment rather than an answer, but it's still a good suggestion.

Comment: @Aaron , its too big to fit as comment , anyways I am trying to work on using yours and his suggestion

Comment: @slim i am facing this bug in webMethods  9.10 and its working fine in 9.6

Comment: If you remove the group with `<BR>` in it, and everything thereafter, it works. I've not the patience to go any further, but you have more motivation than I do.

Comment: @slim , sorry i didn't get you , can you please given  an example