# regex for multiple group not working - Java 1.7 to 1.8 - ScriptEngine Rhino to Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I had a regex problem as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322744/java-javascript-regex-code-fails-on-1-8-as-compared-to-1-7-using-javax-script)

The string is following : `<SPAN>06-24-2015  11:28AM  0250 01 90775 05342</SPAN>`

The JS code on 1.7 Java is working fine : 
Regex :

`/<span>(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4})\\s*?(\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}\\s*?(?:am|pm))\\s*?(?:<\\/SPAN><BR\\/?><SPAN>)?\\s*?((\\d[ -]*?){13,17})\\s*?<\\/span>/i`

But the same was  not working in 1.8 Java as described in the question shared on top .
Getting the suggestion in that question , I created my regex group by group and come to know that only the last part of regex is not working in 1.8 .

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        String js = "var fileSrc = '<SPAN>06-24-2015  11:28AM  0250 01 90775 05342</SPAN>';"
                + "var trans_regex = /<span>(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4})\\s*?(\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}\\s*?(?:am|pm))\\s*?(?:<\\/SPAN><BR\\/?><SPAN>)?\\s*?((\\d[ -]*?){13,17})\\s*?/i;"
                + "print('executed regex result : ' + trans_regex.exec(fileSrc) ) ; ";

        Object result = engine.eval(js);
```

In the above code shared the regex is truncated to :

```
/<span>(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4})\\s*?(\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}\\s*?(?:am|pm))\\s*?(?:<\\/SPAN><BR\\/?><SPAN>)?\\s*?((\\d[ -]*?){13,17})\\s*?/i
```

which gives result as :

```
executed regex result : <SPAN>06-24-2015  11:28AM  0250 01 90775,06-24-2015,11:28AM,0250 01 90775,5
```

And the actual regex is :

```
/<span>(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4})\\s*?(\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}\\s*?(?:am|pm))\\s*?(?:<\\/SPAN><BR\\/?><SPAN>)?\\s*?((\\d[ -]*?){13,17})\\s*?<\\/span>/i
```

Can anyone please suggest what should be done to make the actual regex work again on 1.8 .

The actual JS regex can be found here https://regex101.com/r/ARqNJ4/1

**EDIT**

> In 1.7 the scripting Engine is Rhino and in 1.8 its Nashorn

**EDIT 2**

As per suggestion in the comment the truncated buggy regex is following :

**String to be matched** :`<SPAN>0250 01 90775 05342</SPAN>`

Regex  used so far  :

```
/<span>\\s*?((\\d[ -]*?){13,17})\\s*?/i
```

Output (not the required one ):

```
executed regex result : <SPAN>0250 01 90775,0250 01 90775,5
```

Regex working in 1.7 :

```
/<span>\\s*?((\\d[ -]*?){13,17})\\s*?<\\/span>/i
```

Comment: Remember JavaScript and Java are different. Features in one language aren't necessarily present in the other.

Comment: @evolutionxbox , I agree .But the code is working fine in 1.7 .So , I am looking for any pointers on the last group of my regex which is not working .May be any workaround !

Comment: I'd check the changelog of Java 1.8 as it sounds like something has changed.

Comment: @evolutionxbox in 1.8 there is a new JS engine , Nashorn

Comment: Is there a chunk of regex (near the front) that you can change to `.*` and still demonstrate the problem? It gives potential answerers more focus on where to look. Or remove a chunk of regex that's working OK, and also remove the corresponding part of the input string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could check, all you need to do is to add `[^<]*?` before the closing `<\\/span\\>` . Also, you don't need to escape the starting `<` of the last span. So, this is this script:

```
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String js = "var fileSrc = '<SPAN>06-24-2015  11:28AM  0250 01 90775 05342</SPAN>';"
            + "var trans_regex = /\\<span\\>(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4})\\s*?(\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}\\s*?(?:am|pm))\\s*?(?:<\\/SPAN><BR\\/?><SPAN>)?\\s*?((\\d[ -]*?){13,17})\\s*?[^<]*?\\<\\/span\\>/i ;"
            + "print('executed regex result : ' + trans_regex.exec(fileSrc) ) ; "
            + "var t_time = trans_regex.exec(fileSrc)[2];"
            + "var t_cc = trans_regex.exec(fileSrc)[3];"
            + "print(\" time \" + t_time)";

    Object result = engine.eval(js);
```

Yields to this:

```
executed regex result : <SPAN>06-24-2015  11:28AM  0250 01 90775 05342</SPAN>,06-24-2015,11:28AM,0250 01 90775,5
 time 11:28AM
```

#### Update - explanation and alternatives

This is the last group of the original regex: `((\\d[ -]*?){13,17})`. It looks tricky to me, however, I don't know the intention behind this. What it does:

1. match **one** digit
2. match **zero or more** space or hyphen
3. Repeat step 1 and two it at least 13, at most 17 times.

This is really tricky because the zero or more space or hypen can match anywhere. I believe the intention was something like this:

Considering the string `0250 01`. The leading `'0'` would match 1 digit and 0 other characters. Same for the `'2'` and `'5'`. Then, `'0 '` would match one digit and one space. And so on, up to 13-17 digits.

Apparently, the Nashorn engine cannot handle this construct. If I add this print statement:

```
+ "print (trans_regex.exec(fileSrc));"
```

then I'll get this result:

```
<SPAN>06-24-2015  11:28AM  0250 01 90775 05342</SPAN>,06-24-2015,11:28AM,0250 01 90775,5
```

Which tells me that `((\\d[ -]*?){13,17})` matched `0250 01 90775`, which is only 11 digits. So my 'fix' just catches the rest of the characters up the the start of a closing `<\span>`.

According to [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0v0nTD/1/), your logic should match.

**Workaround 1**

You can make the hyphen-or-space part greedy. I.e. remove the `?` after the `*`:

```
((\\d[ -]*){13,17})
```

I would go with this one.

**Workaround 2**

You can specify some more repetitions, 19 in this case:

```
((\\d[ -]*?){13,19})
```

I'm afraid in this case you'll have to change the lower bound too.

Comment: can you please explain yours answer

Comment: It's just trial and error. Adding `[^<]*?` will make the regex match. It consumes every character that's not a `<` character. Once you have a match, ` trans_regex.exec(fileSrc)` gives an array that contains the groups, and that's it. I'll update the answer with more details soon.

Comment: what do you mean by greedy in Workaround 1 , nice explanation overall

Comment: @softxide greedy means match as much as possible. I.e. `.*h` will match everything up to the last 'h'. On the other hand, the non-greedy `.*?h` will match up to the first 'h'. In your case, this distinction should affect performance only because you use quite precise character classes.